# Ubuntu 20.04: ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:20.04.18) but 1:20.04.28 is to be installed

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I am trying to install kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 fresh installation

```
$ sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libreoffice-kf5 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libreoffice-plasma but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:20.04.18) but 1:20.04.28 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did you try 'sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is already the newest version (1:20.04.28).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: try runing these commands they should fix broken packages 'sudo apt-get update –fix-missing'     'sudo dpkg –configure -a'     'sudo apt-get install -f'

Comment: all ran successfully, but still same issue

Comment: I guess `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` package is set to =1:20.04.18 version in the repositories as dependency for the package `ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt`. Instead of `=` it must be `>=`.

Comment: Is universe active? `apt-cache policy` please add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping, I added focal-updates universe and now everything works perfectly

Comment: Why would you try to install kubuntu desktop from the GNOME distro?  Changing desktop environments is an extremely messy task that involves switching dozens of system level packages and almost never works properly.  This is why Ubuntu comes in different [official flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).  You can download and install [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by adding these two lines in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
```

and running these commands

```
# apt update
# apt upgrade
# apt install kubuntu-desktop
```